# What are the advantages of educational account of github?

Tags: github

My advisor signed up for the education plan of github. He couldn't make the repository that he created private. Is there any way to do that? Other than that what are the advantages of the educational plan?

Comment: Maybe you can provide the answer that you got from github support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked support@github and they fixed the problem. Basically with educational licenses, you get 5 private repositories and if it's a organization you get as many as you want. We got 20 for our lab.

Answer (score 0):

Did he sign up for an organization or a private account?

When he has an organization he has to add you as the members of the organization and either give you manager access or create a private repo for you.

But the easiest way to get help would be hitting up [@GitHubHelp](https://twitter.com/#!/githubhelp) on Twitter or support@github.com

Comment: He applied for free org group I think.

Thanks. I'll ask support@github then.